# How do I formulate a query on the data returned by ResourceData?

Tags: dataset, curated-data

I struggle to answer the following question:

> Use `ResourceData["New Orleans Slave Sales 1856-1861"]` to answer the following question:
>   How many rows in which the NotaryFirstName contains the letter "e" (or "E") have no value (i.e. missing value) in the Price field?

Here is the beginning of my code where I could only find all the names in the data:

```
slavelist = ResourceData["New Orleans Slave Sales 1856-1861"]
namelist = slavelist[All, "NotaryFirstName"]
```

Comment: `Length@slavelist[
 Select[
  (! MissingQ@#NotaryFirstName && 
      StringContainsQ[#NotaryFirstName, "e"]) &&
    MissingQ@#Price
   &]]`
Please read the documentation for `Dataset`, which has examples extremely similar to this question. I am voting to close this question as a) it's an obvious homework question and b) the answer is easily found in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making this post to record the answer given by @CarlLange in a comment to the question.

Evaluating

```
slavelist = ResourceData["New Orleans Slave Sales 1856-1861"];
```

assigns a dataset to `slavelist`, so any valid dataset query can be used to extract information from `slavelist`. In this case, the appropriated query is

```
query = 
  slavelist[
    Select[
      ! MissingQ @ #NotaryFirstName && 
      StringContainsQ[#NotaryFirstName, "e", IgnoreCase -> True] && 
      MissingQ @ #Price &]];
```

and then

```
Length @ query
```

> `1997`

Note: I have modified Lange's code a little to make it conform more exactly to the criteria given in the question.